# How do i get my internet to work?

Tags: wireless, networking

I recently built a computer and installed ubuntu on it. The wireless i put into it was taken out of a **HP Pavilion Slimline s5-1024 Desktop**. I checked on the internet and the wireless card is  **Ralink corp RT5390 wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe**.  Every time i get on my computer, it acts as if everything is ok, but i cant find my home internet and most of the options are dark so i cant click on them. I am very new to all of this and i would just like my wifi to work. would installing a driver for it help? Do i have to get a different adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know exactly what Wifi you have, this should be easy.

Ubuntu has a software tool that allows it to use a Windows driver for your Wifi card.
It's called Ndiswrapper. If you have no access to internet you can use the install media that you installed with to install Ndiswrapper (It's on the disk image).

[Use this Ubuntu help page as a reference.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper)

**1.** Download the Wifi driver for the card from HP. You already linked the site so this should be easy enough. Find a way to get it to the Ubuntu computer. Usb key, burning to a cd, whatever.

**2.** Install Ndiswrapper.

**3.** Install the Windows Wifi driver from step one using Ndiswrapper.